# Deploy Application Gateway with self-signed certificate with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform deployment that deploys an Application Gateway in Azure to control traffic to an Application Service Environment hosting an application. Currently, the deployment creates a listener that is using port 80/HTTP but now that I have everything working as I want, I want to modify the deployment to do SSL termination at the App Gateway. I have created a self-signed certificate for testing purposes and I have loaded the certificate into Azure Key Vault. I am now trying to figure out how to modify my deployment to use the certificate. The only thing I can find is the need to add the `ssl_certificate_name` property to the listener but I know there is more to it than that. How do I tell Terraform "where" the certificate is?

Comment: you can pull the values from the kv at deployment time, not sure if crappyform can do that, arm templates can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a Application Gateway could not support get references directly from a certificate stored in key vault, you could upvote to [support SSL certificates stored in Key Vault secrets for listeners and backend HTTP settings on Application Gateway](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/31089529-support-ssl-certificates-stored-in-key-vault-secre).

From this [document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#data), a `http_listener` block only supports reference a certificate via `ssl_certificate_name`, so you could reference the certificate from the `name` and `data` attribute in `ssl_certificate` block. In this block, the `data` requires the contents of the Authentication Certificate which should be used. Also, you could use a built-in function [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#built-in-functions) to read certificate `base64encode` contents. For example, to read a file: `${file("path.txt")}`.

```
ssl_certificate {
     name     = "default"
     data     = "${base64encode(file("mycert.pfx"))}"
     password = "XXXXXXX"
  }
```

and

```
  http_listener {
    name                           = "https"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "default"
    frontend_port_name             = "https"
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name           = "default"
  }
```

You could get more scenarios about [attaching SSL certificate to Azure application gateway in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825236/attaching-ssl-certificate-to-azure-application-gateway-in-terraform) and [Azure Application Gateway with end-to-end SSL](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/619) .

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was very helpful. Unless I am missing something, there is no documentation for the `ssl_certificate` block in the Terraform documentation for `Application Gateway`.

Comment: I also noticed that, but I found people always use that block. You could read it in the example scenarios. I think this should be the same utility with `authentication_certificate` block in application gateway but add extra `password` parameter.